# Why do I run into a blank page whenever I use react router , no matter what the version or use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I have tried many versions of RouterDOM and all I get when I use it is a blank page. This is just one example which I included BrowserReact in index.js. Still a blank page.

Can someone please help?

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import About from "./About";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={Home}>
          This is in home
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help. Do you see console errors? Build errors? What is rendered? What does `Home` look like?

Comment: For that matter, show us index.js.

Comment: You've included the react-native tag. Is this a react native project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your component in tags?
The React Router [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#routes-and-route) says you should use your component as JSX.

Like so:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
  </Routes>
```